# python : how to variables many strings in one line in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple variables and I need to write them in CSV file , but CSV reads a sequences, so it writes every character in one line, and I need all of variables in one line with space separating between them
 For example, if I have these variables:

```
pdate=30/03/2017 
ptime=17:17:30 
outlet1= 12345
outlet2=6789
```

so i want them in CSV like this:

```
30/03/2017   17:17:30    12345    6789
```

and if I got more data, it will write them in the next line like :

```
30/03/2017   17:17:30    12345    6789
30/03/2017   17:19:10    34354    4335
```

I managed to do it by turning every variable to index inside one list and used "zip" to write all the lists in one line, but I would like to see if there is another way to do that ?
here is my code

```
    outlet1.append(12345)
    outlet2.append(6789)
    pdate.append("30/03.2017")
    ptime.append("17:17:30")
    with open('file.csv','a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ');
            writer.writerows(zip(pdate,ptime,outlet1,outlet2))
        f.close()
```

Comment: I ziped lists, and tht works fine, but I need away to do it without using lists.

Comment: Yes, because a list with a single element that is a string is not the same thing as just the string. Look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are zipping *strings*. When you iterate over a string, you iterate over the individual characters. Just use `writer.writerow([pdate, ptime, outlet1, outlet2])`

Note, it is `writer.writerow` instead of `writer.writerows`

Comment: Yes with writer.writerow worked totally fine as I wanted. I tried that command before, but I used writer.writerows